# In VBA how to keep two worksheets and delete other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone！ I'm trying to write a method in VBA to keep 2 worksheets and delete others at the same time.
I already did the one that will keep one worksheet and delete others like this:

```
Sub delete_all_pages_except_main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If ws.Name <> "Home Page" Then
    ws.Delete
    End If
    
    Next ws
    
    End Sub
```

And I try to write it like this

```
If (ws.Name <> "Home Page" Or ws.Name <> "Data")
```

But VBA would accept it.

Can you guys help? Thank you.

Comment: `And` instead of `Or`.

Comment: The code you are using can be translated to `If(1 <> 2 or 1 <> 1)`, which is always `True`.

Comment: If Instr("Home Page,Data",ws.name) = 0 then ws.delete

Comment: Yes, you guys are definitely right, thank you.

Comment: Another way to see this is to work out the opposite of your statement (`<>` becomes `=` and `Or` becomes `And`). Therefore, the opposite is `ws.Name = "Home Page" And ws.Name = "Data"` which is obviously always `False` and so the opposite of that is always `True`

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
    Sub delete_all_pages_except_main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim boo As Boolean
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    arr = Array("Home Page", "Data")
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        boo = NoDel(ws.Name, arr)
        If boo <> True Then ws.Delete
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

    Function NoDel(ws As String, warr As Variant) As Boolean
        NoDel = False
        For i = LBound(warr, 1) To UBound(warr, 1)
            If warr(i) = ws Then NoDel = True
        Next i
    End Function
```

Comment: oops I did not see the comment that says to use instr function which is more convenient than the script above I had written some time ago. I kinda forget vba shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Sheets With Exceptions

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a specified workbook, writes all the sheet names            '
'               not specified in an Exceptions array to a Result array, and    '
'               using the Result array deletes all the sheets in one go.       '
' Remarks:      This solution applies to worksheets and chartsheets.           '
'               Since there is no Sheet object, the For Next loop (instead     '
'               of the For Each Next loop) and the Object type have            '
'               to be used.                                                    '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub deleteSheets(Book As Workbook, Exceptions As Variant)
    
' Program
    
    Dim SheetsCount As Long: SheetsCount = Book.Sheets.Count
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(SheetsCount)
    
    Dim sh As Object, i As Long, j As Long
    j = -1
    For i = 1 To SheetsCount: GoSub checkName: Next i
    
    If j = -1 Then GoTo NothingToDelete
    If j = SheetsCount - 1 Then GoTo NoExceptions
    
    GoSub deleteSheetsInOneGo
    
    MsgBox "Deleted '" & j + 1 & "' sheets.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
    Exit Sub
    
' Subroutines

checkName:
    Set sh = Book.Sheets(i)
    If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
        j = j + 1
        Result(j) = sh.Name
    End If
    Return

deleteSheetsInOneGo:
    ReDim Preserve Result(j)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Book.Sheets(Result).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Return

' Labels

NothingToDelete:
    MsgBox "Sheets already deleted.", vbCritical, "Nothing to Delete"
    Exit Sub

NoExceptions:
    MsgBox "Cannot delete all sheets.", vbCritical, "No Exceptions"
    Exit Sub

End Sub

' Usage Example
Sub runDeleteSheets()
    Dim SheetNames As Variant: SheetNames = Array("Home Page", "Data")
    deleteSheets ThisWorkbook, SheetNames
End Sub
```